# meaning of async in this code

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

```
var response = $.ajax({
            url: "/Master/chkDuptindustryid",
            type: "POST",
            data: "{ 'systemid':'" + systemid + "'}",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
```

Comment: Did you check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ?

Comment: It will run synchronously, so it will wait for it to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting async to false means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called.  If you set async: true then that statement will begin it's execution and the next statement will be called regardless of whether the async statement has completed yet.

The first A in AJAX is Asynchronous. That function returns before the AJAX call returns (or at least it can).  There are only two options:

Make the AJAX call synchronous (not recommended) with the async: false option; or
Change your way of thinking. Instead of returning HTML from the function you need to passin a callback to be called when the AJAX call succeeds

Answer (score 1):

What is says: you can do a synchronous call instead of asynchronous one, which is a default.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active. **As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR
>   ($.Deferred) is deprecated;** you must use the success/error/complete
>   callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR
>   object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

Answer (score 1):

Taken from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> async (default: true)
>   Type: Boolean
>   By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

Sp basically, it would force the request to be made synchronously and lock the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8,
>   the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you
>   must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the
>   corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the
>   deprecated jqXHR.success().

[source](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)